# Template printing member variable without an object

Tags: c++, templates

This is weird (MSVC2012):

```
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:

    int membervar;
};

template< int (MyClass::*var) > struct A 
{
   void print()
   {
       cout << var;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct A <&MyClass::membervar> object;

   object.print();
}
```

This code compiles and actually couts "1". Where does it get it?? What object does the membervar belong to? I thought I needed an object to access a data member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code compiles and actually couts "1". Where does it get it?

What happens is that in:

```
int (MyClass::*var) = &MyClass::membervar;
cout << var;
```

Because there is no shift operator that takes a stream and a member pointer, another shift operator gets chosen:

```
std::ostream::operator<<(bool);
```

In other words, it prints `var` after converting it to `bool`.

Comment: So what I was trying to do is a non-sense, I would have expected it not to compile at all..

Answer (score 0):

> This code compiles and actually couts "1". Where does it get it??

What you are trying to print is a *pointer to a member function*.

It's getting converted to a `bool`.  And that bool is evaluating as `true`, meaning it's non-zero.